# Can activeadmin be used with sinatra or other non-rails apps?

Tags: sinatra, activeadmin, rack

I looked at the docs and wiki, but could not figure out for certain if activeadmin has a hard dependency on rails?

Would it be possible to use it as a drop in admin panel for a sinatra or pure rack app?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, ActiveAdmin is Rails only.  You can figure out dependencies by looking at the [Gemfile](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/Gemfile).  You might want to look at [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/) instead,.